# Best way to override Hibernate's lazy loading in this instance

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

Suppose you have class `B` with lazily loaded property `c`. And that this is fine everywhere in the system except the following:

You have a class `A` with property `b` of class `B`. Whenever you load an entity of type `A` you want to load the full `a.b.c` chain non-lazily.

Is there a way to set up this type of logic in Hibernate?

**Edit:**
A property can also be defined with a `formula` that is a SQL expression. The documentation says:

> A powerful feature is derived
>   properties. These properties are by
>   definition read-only. The property
>   value is computed at load time. You
>   declare the computation as an SQL
>   expression. This then translates to a
>   SELECT  clause subquery in the SQL
>   query that loads an instance:

```
<property name="totalPrice"
    formula="( SELECT SUM (li.quantity*p.price) FROM [...] )"/>
```

This would work if it was a Hibernate query that returned a Hibernate object.

**Edit 2:**
Other thoughts include declaring a class `B2` which is exactly the same as `B` except it's `C` property isn't lazy loaded.

**So far the options are**:

1. Rely on a query every time, as suggested by skaffman.
2. Use a formula in a property to get fields I want, but no object.
3. Create a `B2` class with non lazy `b.c`. (kind of ugly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HQL, something like this:

```
from A as a
    inner join fetch a.b
    inner join fetch b.c
```

Comment: For queries that's good. But if I traverse to a `.a` property of another object, I won't get `a.b.c` in one shot.

Comment: That';s true, but if you configure `B.c` to be lazily loaded, then that's how it's going to behave. If you want to override that, then you need to write your queries to explicitly fetch it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not a common case in your app (and it shouldn't be), you can manually initialize the dependent objects after fetching the `A` object, using [`Hibernate.initialize(..)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize(java.lang.Object))